# Vue Js 2 error reload

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm working with Vue Js 2 and the server it's Nginx.

I have the next code:

```
const routes = [
   {
    path: '/design-dashboard',
    component: DesignDashboard,
    meta: {
        forAuth : true
    }
  },
  {
   path: '/dashboard/new/create',
    component: ProductLineEdit,
    meta: {
        forAuth : true
    }
  }
];

export default new VueRouter({
 mode: 'history',
 routes
});
```

The problem is when the url has more than 1 sections o slashes '/', for example it works with "/design-dashboard", and don't works with "/dashboard/new/create" only works throught a vue router link or a router.push() method, but when I reload or try to access directly with the url in the browser doesn't work.

I also added this htaccess code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

As I said before everything works fine with only one section or sliash '/ like for example "/design-dashboard"

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this adding the .htaccess and transform to a nginx code and adding an slash '/' in src attribute in script tag

```
 <script src="/dist/app.js">
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to configure the nginx server using `htaccess` which is intended for `apache`.

Try to configure nginx, with configs like this:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

Comment: I think is more related with "children" stuffs in Vue router